# How can I have CKEditor instances that have different sizes or different configurations?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have set up the size of my CKEditor window as follows:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

   config.height = 350;
   config.width = '100%';
};
```

But I would like to have more than one size. A large and a small size.

Can anyone tell me how I can change the size so one instance is different from another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the settings when you initialize the CKEditors, instead of rely of the config-file only.

markup

```
<textarea id="test1"></textarea>
<textarea id="test2"></textarea>
```

script

```
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace('test1', { width:"800px", height:"200px" }); 
CKEDITOR.replace('test2', { width:"400px", height:"100px" }); 
</script>
```

[image]

you can also define different toolbars :

```
CKEDITOR.replace('test1', { width:"600px", height:"300px", toolbar:'myToolBar' });
```